# > and >> operators have no effect

Tags: linux, cat

when trying to write the output of a php script to a file I get the weirdest error.
I use:

```
#php daily.php > error/daily
```

Well, all this does is output it in the console anyway. The file (error/daily) is untouched.

error/daily has chmod 777.
Different constructs like

```
#php daily.php >> error/daily
```

don't work either. The output of daily.php just keeps being output in the console...

Got any ideas on this? :/ Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Now using

```
#php daily.php 2> error/daily
```

it outputs nothing in the console.

But error/daily is untouched, nothing is written to it.

Another UPDATE:

```
#php daily.php 2>> error/daily
```

works as expected (appends error output to file), while

```
#php daily.php 2> error/daily
```

simply empties the file and writes nothing into it.
Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

So this is at the shell prompt? Those parentheses cause the enclosed command to be executed in a new invocation of the shell; the redirects will apply to the output of the shell itself, of which there is none. Commands that the shell executes will still print their output to the console. Just drop the parentheses; they're unnecessary and the source of your problem.

Comment: No, I actually added the parentheses because it didn't work without. I thought maybe that would work.
Well, as they make no difference, I'll edit my question and delete them.

Comment: Well, I wondered if it was some odd property of the `php` executable itself, so I tried this on my system; it worked fine. Very strange.

Comment: Yup, I let two friends try it on their computers - worked fine. Really weird.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal, programs have two outputs : standard output and error output. By default both display in the console.

The > (and >>) operator redirects the standard output to a file but leaves the error output in the console.

Since it seems you are trying to redirect errors to a file, php must be writing to the error output. To accomplish what you want to do you must do

```
php daily.php 2> error/daily
```

If you want to redirect both outputs you can also do

```
php daily.php 2> error/daily 1>&2
```

**Edit**: Don't do that.
If you want to redirect both outputs, redirect in different files. For instance:

```
php daily.php 2> error/daily 1> output.txt
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, thanks. But the standard output apparently was discarded instead of written to error/daily, because the file was untouched.
--edit: Yup, when I use 2>, it outputs nothing. But the file is untouched yet again.

Comment: I don't know what your daily.php does but it's possible that nothing comes out of the standard output. Something which is likely for a maintenance script executed daily.

Comment: Well, it gets even more weird.

#php daily.php 2> error/daily

empties the file and writes nothing to it.

#php daily.php 2>> error/daily

writes the errors to the file (as in, works as I need it).
So...why does #php daily.php 2> error/daily not work?

Comment: AND 2>> writes BOTH error AND standard output to the file. (without adding 1>&2)

Comment: It appears I have made a mistake. Don't add 1>&2 , that's why you file is empty in the first case since the file is erased to write the error and then erased again to write the standard error. Are you sure there really is something on the standard output? If you didn't add 1>&2, i'm not sure i can help you. Maybe php does something i don't know, but i doubt that.